# Android share app VIA etc

Tags: android, share

I saw in many apps this.. When you click on a menu, than an other menu show up, and you can share your app VIA e-mail, twitter, bluetooth, facebook, etc.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the SEND intent action to share a [market uri](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#marketintent) pointing to your app.

The chooser will list any installed app that has declared it can share data.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");

intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "App Name");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Check out this cool app http://market.android.com/details?id=com.example.yourpackagename");

Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Tell a friend about App Name");
startActivity(chooser);
```