# Android: Share App Popup

Tags: android, popup, share

I was wondering if there was a way to have the same menu as the android "App Sharing" menu that pops up when you select an app inside of my application. So I would have a button listening for on click and once clicked it would run sharepopup();

Or would it be possible to call the "App Sharing" app from within my app?

Thanks!

EDIT: I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558977/android-share-app-via-etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the app popup is just styled as an `AlertDialog` with items:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Popup");
    final CharSequence[] items = {"item A", "Item b"};
     builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
           switch(Item){
            /////Do stuff;
           }
        }
    }).show();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This works well also, just more coding then the method that I found. :)